# Passing several struct arguments to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, file

First I entered height and width of a matrix.

Then I entered several arguments that I need to send to a function (and then to do something with previous matrix):

```
typedef struct{
  int red2;
  int stupac2;
  int visina;
  int sirina;
  char boja;
}Tunel;
     
    
while (fscanf(fin, " [%d,%d] v=%d s=%d#%c", &tuneli[p].red2, &tuneli[p].stupac2, &tuneli[p].visina, &tuneli[p].sirina, &tuneli[p].boja) == 5)
{
    p++;
    farbaj(mat,r,s, &tuneli.red2, &tuneli.stupac2, &tuneli.visina, &tuneli.sirina, &tuneli.boja, p);
    proba(tuneli[p].red2, tuneli[p].stupac2);
}

void proba(int tuneli[p].red2, int tuneli[p].stupac2)
{    
    printf("[%d,%d]\n", red2, stupac2);
}
```

With function farbaj I need to pass all parameters from txt.file+2D array I already allocated + rows and columns of that matrix.

I dont know how many parameters I will have so i cant make objects Tunel no1 or no2. I need to pass these arguments correctly

Comment: Consider editing your question to include a well formatted [mcve] and a better description of the error than what you currently have. Nobody knows what "I didn't succeed" means especially without the context of the functions you're trying to call.

Comment: Better ? @RetiredNinja

Comment: No, not really, but `void proba(int tuneli[p].red2, int tuneli[p].stupac2)` is wrong. You want `void proba(int red2, int stupac2)` for that particular function declaration.

Comment: Can you pass whole structure as parameter and then just use fields that you need or this is wrong for your solution?

Comment: OK, i send like tuneli[p].red2 and recieve like int *red2 and it works. Thank you

Comment: @dunajski, i have 2d array with dots '.' and i need parameteres from struct to replace these dots with other chars

Comment: So use this fields as @Retired Ninja mentioned or just pass whole structure and use only those fields.